# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, memory, memory-management

Hot to solve this problem and why it happens?

**Zend Server Log:**

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 538798977 bytes) in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\test\modules\main.php on line 3

The file `main.php` does not produce any error, if it's executed directly from browser. However, if I use its functions from another PHO file, then Zend Log prints the above-mentioned error.

Comment: did you try to increase the memory limit?

Comment: 128MB of used memory? What does this script *do*?

Comment: You tried to allocate 500 megs of ram in a single go? Goodness, did you try to read in a massive CSV at once? If you did, read them in one line at a time instead and process them that way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have also encounted this problem.

Increase the following variables so that your page execution will not stop:

- `max_input_time`
- `memory_limit`
- `max_execution_time`

Comment: ...not technically *wrong* so no -1 but probably a bad suggestion. The original error indicates that you're (probably) using *way* too much memory - there's something  smelly in your code (infinite loop?).  To put it differently, if your page consumes that much memory every time if runs, for your host's sake hopefully you don't have many users :)

Answer (score 10):

Either increase the memory limit in `php.ini`, or try to optimise any large data structures (like arrays) out of your application.

In any case, if your PHP application is using 128MB of RAM, something is probably going wrong.

Also, as noted by Fluffeh in the comments, what on earth are you doing to utilise 500MB of RAM?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

[php.net/memory_limit](http://php.net/memory_limit)

It will take unlimited memory usage of server.

Comment: But if you're running CLI mode it's very useful.

Comment: @superarts.org & others: there is a way to change CLI settings for PHP. Type `php --ini` and edit the right file.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to user1427811 you can monitor `time_limit` and `memory_limit` before and after downloading the file:

```
function custom_put_contents($source_url='',$local_path=''){

    $time_limit = ini_get('max_execution_time');
    $memory_limit = ini_get('memory_limit');

    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');      

    $remote_contents=file_get_contents($source_url);
    $response=file_put_contents($local_path, $remote_contents);

    set_time_limit($time_limit);
    ini_set('memory_limit', $memory_limit); 

    return $response;
}
```