# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3 bytes) after ini_set

Tags: php, memory, ini, sqlanywhere

At first, I've already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061917/ini-setmemory-limit-in-php-5-3-3-is-not-working-at-all) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264253/allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted).

I've received the following error:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 220 bytes)`

I'm working with `php 5.4`and `sql Anywhere 11`.

The solution to this is according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter) is putting `ini_set('memory_set',-1);` in my `php-file`, but after doing this I get another error:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3 bytes)`

**EDIT**: my code is

```
<?php
    ini_set('memory_set',-1);
    $connect = sasql_connect("UID=username;PWD=pass");
    echo "Connection succeed";

    $result = sasql_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM table1, table2");

    if(!$result){
    echo "sasql_query failed";
    return 0;
    } else {
    echo "query completed successfully\n";
    sasql_result_all($result);
    }
    sasql_close($conn);
?>
```

I hope someone can help me.

**SOLUTION**:
I've found the solution: I've added a `WHERE (columnName1 = columnName2)`, split the result and it works again, relative fast!

```
<?php
    $connect = sasql_connect("UID=username;PWD=pass");
    if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };
    $results_page = 100;
    $start_from = ($page-1) * $results_page + 1;    
    $result = sasql_query($connect, "SELECT TOP $results_page START AT $start  * 
                    FROM table1, table2 WHERE (columnName1 = columnName2)");

    if(!$result){
    echo "sasql_query failed";
    return 0;
    } else {
    echo "query completed successfully\n";
    sasql_result_all($result);
    }
    sasql_close($conn);
?>
```

Ofcourse I add in my `php-page` a `<a href="<?php echo $page -1; ?>">Previous</a>` and a `<a href="<?php echo $page + 1; ?>">Next</a>`

Thanks to you all for the help!

Comment: Make sure you don't have an infinite loop or  a never ending recursive function.

Comment: @Virus721 I added my code and I guess I don't do anything wrong in this?

Comment: I don't know what is sasql, but i don't think it comes from here, unless you're extracting a large amount of data.

Comment: That was the problem, I'm extracting a lot of amount, that's the reason I needed to expand the memory. Thanks anyway for your help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use

```
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
```

and not "memory_set". Also, look out for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5263981/2729140 (Suhosin extension has it's own memory limit setting).

If your script needs a lot of memory, then you should try and revise it. One thing to be aware of are unlimited SQL queries.

Your tables can have A LOT of records, so it's wise to always limit your queries. If you need to fetch all the records from the table, then you should do it by pages, using `LIMIT ... OFFSET` SQL constructs.

Comment: I used also a part of your answer, the `SQL Anywhere 11` is build this way: `SELECT TOP 20 START AT 1 * FROM table1, table2`. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

after many attempts I have identifed that if php-pecl-apc is installed the php config memory_limit can be reduced to 48M or less and it stops the Allowed memory size exhausted
error.